# Will this audio/video cable work with a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10, video-out

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 and I'm looking for a cable that will allow me to output audio and video to a TV. I found this on a website and I was wondering if anyone has tried it or knows if it will work?

[image]

Comment: A link or some part no.of the cable would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As I had commented to @onik's answer: If this cable does not have a DAC (Digital to Analogue Converter), this cable will not work.

I also found a search result about a [scam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6Vu2gGhzVo) related to this kind of cable, which again confirms this. Since I am unable to view the video (restriction at my work) I am unable to see to comment more on it.

Comment: btw, the poster of that video misunderstood the purpose of the cable. It's not a HDMI->RCA cable, it's a HDMI->VGA cable with 3xRCA cables, 2 for audio and one extra (don't know why).

Answer (score 1):

A source link could give us more information, but I see no reason this wouldn't work, since it uses the correct port and that port also supports HDMI, which means that video output is supported.

Comment: IMHO, HDMI deals with digital content, while the other end in the image has RCA pins, which deal with analogue only. Unless there is a DAC some where in that cable, I seriously doubt. Having said that it is only my hunch.

Comment: My bad, confused this with a component cable. That being said, analog video output has been supported on several models even through the headphone jack, and there are official RCA cables for the tabs, see [here](http://www.thegalaxytab.com/2011/01/01/samsung-galaxy-tab-rca-video-cable-review/) for a video review.